# "from import" in python

Tags: python, import

there are two modules. code in python 2.7

m1.py:

```
x=2
__y__=5

def foo():
    print x
```

m2.py:

```
from m1 import foo
foo()    #output 2
print x #output error
```

my question is how function foo in m2.py knows the value of x from m1.py.  Based on my understanding, "from m1 import foo" assigns m1.foo to foo in m2.py. I didnt import x from m1.
Thanks

Comment: Function `foo` is in `m1.py`, so it knows about everything from that file.

Comment: The whole of `m1` is run for the import, so `x` has been assigned from the point of view of `foo()`.

Comment: do you mean the x is saved in foo function like closure? if yes, how can we prove?

Comment: @cppython: Basically, yes.  The function always remains linked to the environment it was defined in, even if you import it somewhere else.

Comment: @cppython Yes, you could understand it like that. The `from module import name` will run the full module you are importing, and *additionally* will make `name` also locally available to the importing module. That does not affect the references `m1` is using though.

Comment: is there any way we can prove? such as  : can we print x from foo object?

Comment: @cppython: `foo` already does print x when you call it.

Comment: "The function always remains linked to the environment it was defined in"   where i can find the "linked"?

Comment: for example: in closure. we can find value from foo.__closure__[0].cell_contents. for my case, where i can find the link

Comment: @cppython: `foo.__globals__` is the dictionary of global variables from where `foo` was defined.  `x` will be there since in your example it was a global variable.

Comment: thanks BrebBarn. i found it foo.__globals__["x"].  I would like to accept this answer this my solution. can you post on Answer Section?

Answer (score 1):

Its all a matter of what's known as scope and some degree to how assignments work in Python. Each module has its own namespace (think of it like a box) where variables you define in it are valid.

```
x = 0
```

This variable in your m1.py is known as a global variable, meaning all other objects in the m1.py module can see it and use it, for example:

```
print(x) # would output 0
foo() # would also output 0
```

When you import foo to m2.py and call the foo function it is accessing the x you defined in m1.py. Because x has not been defined in m2.py you will get an error if you try to reference it. Even if you assigned x to another value in m2.py, the foo function would still print 0 because it is accessing the x from m1.py.